# Is it possible to create multiple socket for same client in java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Two Sockets so that a serve two different task simultaneously without threading to the same client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i create multiple sockets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076760/can-i-create-multiple-sockets-in-java)

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Typically, they would use different local ports to access the same server. If you want to do that without threads, you should use SocketChannel and configure it for non-blocking IO. However, non-blocking IO is more complicated to use.